# MATLAB fwind1 in Python3

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I have MATLAB code I want to convert into python3.
MATLAB EXAMPLE:

```
[r,c] = meshgrid(1:600);   %comment matrix 1:600
filt =  (sqrt((r-300).^2+(c-300).^2)>=100) & (sqrt((r-300).^2+(c-300).^2)<=180);
h = fwind1(filt,hamming(11));
hff=imfilter(I,h);
```

I'm looking for a python equivalent. 
I see that scikit-image's [coverage table](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.11.x/coverage_table.html) ends at 0.11.X and it was not implemented.
I see scipy.signal has a [firwin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html#scipy.signal.firwin) and [firwin2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin2.html#scipy.signal.firwin2) but I am not familiar with how to match the parameters if these are even similar.
Can anyone offer some insight?